# Expo push notification not working after build

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

i added expo push notifications they were working  fine in development after build and testing on other device notifications were not working, no channel were created etc.. can you please help i am stuck for weeks on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you please add a few details of your issue to the question? For example the code that is supposed to work but does not and the other approaches you tried to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create firebase project and push key to expo.